# blur text everywhere in ubuntu 14.04 server

Tags: 14.04

I recently installed ubuntu 14.04 server on my hard-disk, not on any virtual machine. When I started it, everywhere I am seeing that text is blur. Eg: the names of folders are blur, name of page on browser tab is blur etc. I am attaching the screen shot. Please help me to sort out this problem[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWLVk.png)

Comment: Weird,that looks like Ubuntu desktop, not server.Have you updated since installing ?

Comment: Hi Damien, I tried to update index using "sudo apt-get update" but got following errors:

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-updates/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-updates/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-backports/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]

Comment: I want to install hadoop here, for this I need to install java7 also. I tried command "sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk" but getting this error:

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package openjdk-7-jdk